# Webapp reachable via domain but not working

Tags: nginx, next.js, webserver

My NextJs application is reachable under https://xyz.pizza/ but doesn't work. For example, if you search for degods, nothing happens when pressing enter.

BUT if you go to the site via http://65.21.252.133:3000/ or http://xyz.pizza:3000/ then everything works fine.

I have completely no idea what causes this issue.
The source code of the project is on GitHub: https://github.com/basti394/nft-research
It's hosted on Hetzner Cloud and runs on NodeJs with Tmux.

My Nginx config:

```
server { # simple reverse-proxy
   server_name  xyz.pizza www.xyz.pizza;

   location /neo4j {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser;
   }

   location = / {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000;
   }

   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.pizza/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.pizza/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

If you need any more information then just ask :)

Comment: It's definity an issue with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to a missing `/` at the end of the `proxy_pass` rule.

```
   location = / {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
   }
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem :(
do I have to add something like this maybe: 
location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by removing the `=` from the location signature.
I also tried it without the trailing `/` at `http://117.0.0.1:3000` and it works as well.

So the location declaration in `nginx.conf` should look something like this:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
}
```